# Project management with MS Teams and MS Sharepoint in a large enterprise

Tags: documentation, organizational-structure

Before the MS Teams "era", documents for (larger) projects existed as folder structures on huge storages as "master system for documentation".

Today, you have got many Sharepoint sites as storage sites for MS Teams. So if you have say an MS Team per department, how to organize cross-department projects?

- If you want to have the documents in the project storage of the department leading the projects, you have to invite members of other departments to your department's area. Documents remain there from the beginning.
- If you want to have an MS Team per project, people find themselves in many MS Teams if they participate in many projects. After project's end, these teams become ghost sites. Ok documents can be moved then and not visible for long time for all project participants.
- ? a better approach in a large enterprise?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to distinguish between persistent project documentation and ephemeral project communication. For project communication and collaboration on documents, services such as MS Teams are great, I'd say even preferable to email since participants don't need to organize information themselves. For persistent storage of project documents, you should use reliable storage under your own control, with reliable backup of course.

Both areas should be governed by the same access policy giving fine-grained access to project members. This means having separate storage areas and teams per project. Since normally access control for file storage and for MS Teams access are managed separately, this creates some administration overhead especially for file storage access groups, but in my opinion this can be kept low if you establish a common way of handling this across projects in your organization.

This would imply that Teams are created per project, which makes a lot of sense in my experience. After a project finishes, the relevant documents should all be in persistent storage, so the MS Teams team can be dissolved.